# ssh key copying shell script

Tags: networking, server, bash, scripts, ssh

I'm quite new to the shell scripting field and i wrote a shell script in centos server to copy its ssh key to some ubuntu host machines. My scipt looks like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
path="/root/keygen/source.txt";
for p in `cat "$path"`;
do echo "$p"
echo "mypassword" | ssh-copy-id root@"$p" --stdin > /dev/null
echo "key copied"
done
```

The file `/root/keygen/source.txt` contains the ip addresses of the ubuntu machines. The root password of the ubuntu host machine is "mypassword" and the local ip is 192.168.0.10

But when i run this script it stuck and asking for the root password of 192.168.0.10 which i already provided in the scipt. Is there any issue in the script ? Please advise me to correct this program so that it will take all Ip adresses in the list i provided and copy its ssh key without asking for password. And please note all the machines have same root password.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to use the bash built-in `read` command to read each IP address from the file in order to loop through them with `for`. Not 100% sure this is on topic here, as the script is running on a Centos machine.

Comment: @Arronical That part of this script is okay i guess as it worked with another script. I guess the issue is with 5th line especially the use of the command echo. And i guess this script will give the same error in ubuntu as well, anyway thanks for the reply.

Comment: Also, I don't think you can just echo the password into `ssh-keygen`, you may need to use `sshpass` with the -p option if you have it on Centos, but it's very insecure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH is not supposed to use passwords provided via pipe for several security reasons. But there are some alternatives:

- SSH_ASKPASS http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ssh.1.html
- sshpass http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/sshpass.1.html

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340366/how-to-make-ssh-receive-the-password-from-stdin